# Pine Script strategy to trigger once per day?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Need help coding *Pine Script v5 strategy* **to trigger once per day**?
Would like to use "bar_index == 0", but do not know how to establish when the bar index re-starts at the beginning of the trading day.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timeframe{dot}change](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_timeframe%7Bdot%7Dchange)

The below tests if it's a new day

```
if timeframe.change("D")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way, but this worked for me:

```
var traded_today = false

//use whatever hours:days for first candle of time series chart
//using 15min here, but can be done using an input()
first_candle = time(timeframe.period, "9:30-9:15:23456"

if (first_candle)
    traded_today := false
    
condition = your_condition and not traded_today

if (condition)
    traded_today := true
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use function

```
strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count=2)
```

count 2 means, one for Entry order and second for Exit order